# Microsoft Account Birthdate

Tags: windows, microsoft-account, parental-controls

The birthdate on my friend's Microsoft Account is incorrect, and this is causing problems with some software such as Google Chrome.

Ten years ago, a private IT contractor set up my friend's Microsoft Account and email address when she set up his last computer. This account was used to purchase software from Microsoft and other companies. She set the birthdate of the account to when she created it, added it to a Family group with herself as the "parent." We have no way of reaching her, and we don't want to make a new account and email address.

On his new computer, I used his Microsoft account to log in to Windows the first time. This makes the local Windows account attached to this Microsoft account have Administrator rights.

Recently, the Parental Controls on the new computer were turned on because of the Microsoft account's apparent age, perhaps during a Windows Update. This causes some apps to require parental permission, so Chrome won't work, even though Edge still does.

Since the Microsoft account has an apparent age of 10 years old, these can't be turned off in Settings. After 3 hours of chatting with Microsoft support, they had no solution other than the one on the web page, which is to contact the previous IT person we can't reach. Once the account reaches 13, there is a way on the website to ask to be able to change the birthdate with suitable proof of age, but not before.

The temporary solution suggested by the commenters below works. Since the Windows account has Administrator rights, the parental controls can be turned off in the System configuration app, even though this action is blocked in Settings. Changing the Registry appeared to be too complicated.

For a permanent solution, do you know how to get through to Microsoft to allow a change in birthdate for an account mistakenly under 13?

Comment: Isn't that because *Parental Controls* are set *on*? Why not just turn them off! https://news.microsoft.com/en-in/features/windows-10-parental-controls-feature/

Comment: I can't turn them off, being only 10 years old. The "parent" has to do it.

Comment: If you or others are not Administrators, then the best way is to get help from MS. Who *does* have Admin rights? Only the absent" IT person"? This sounds like a disaster waiting to happen -- a business site with **no** Admin! BTW, there are Registry keys for this: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Parental Controls, but you need to be Admin.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks! That looks promising. The account does have local Admin rights, but the computer is signed into using the Microsoft account which is in someone else's Family Group as a child for some reason, which is why the parental controls are grayed out in the Settings. I don't know why Windows is like this.

Comment: If family controls can be easily circumvented, there's little benefit to them. So long as you're using this Microsoft account and until the business admins fix this, you'll be severely limited in what a fix can do and how long it will last. I'd suggest you need to pursue the business admin. Also, is this a business account, or did the admin set controls on a personal account?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @drmoishepippik I was able to get a workaround.

To turn off parental controls in Windows 11,

1. Open System Configuration app
2. Go to Services tab, list by name and find Parental Controls in the
   list
3. Disable the service by unchecking it
4. Restart

The controls were gone when the machine rebooted.

Apparently the Parental Controls might be turned on again by Windows Update, so this procedure will need to be followed again if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> For a permanent solution, do you know how to get through to Microsoft to allow a change in birthdate for an account mistakenly under 13?

Microsoft has an interactive tool --> [How to change a birth date on a Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/how-to-change-a-birth-date-on-a-microsoft-account-837badbc-999e-54d2-2617-d19206b9540a)

Follow the above link and follow the on screen instructions.

Comment: This doesn't work in my country if the account is under 13. The tool just directs the user to contact the "adult" account that we can't reach. When the account is 13 or older, there is a way to show proof of age.